# 74121 one-shot trigger on inputs A and B - can B be held low continuously?

Tags: analog

74121 one-shot trigger on inputs A and B - can B be held low continuously, or must it transition from high to low at the same time as A?

When I negative trigger on A and B at the same time I get my output pulse as expected.

However, if I keep B low and just trigger on A I get no output pulse.

It looks like both should work according to the truth table.

[74121 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74121)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [DatasheetCafe](http://www.datasheetcafe.com/74121-datasheet-pdf-fairchild/).*

The schematic shows that B is an input to an AND gate. **Q** will be low if **B** is low. This is confirmed by the third line of the truth table.

Answer (score 1):

This logic diagram is read as follows;

This monostable pulse is triggered by any first of 4 combinations of transitions either Ax active low and B active high being True.

It can be retriggered only after one of these active inputs going inactive first to enable the trigger active  edge to go true again.

You can use any combination of inputs  or just one if you like.

Thus if you don't need B, it is asserted to '1'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you need is "So what?" Except for extremely unusual requirements, with a need for a very large timing range, it's always better to not use a one-shot. In the 1970s, when ICs like the 74121 and 9601 were introduced, I advised members of my group to rip the pages out of their catalogs so they wouldn't be tempted to use them. It wasn't my original thought: I learned from bitter personal experience and later saw articles from many others.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:  You can wire the '121 to be triggered from a rising edge, or from a falling edge.

If you want a rising-edge trigger, you trigger the B input, and hard-wire one or both of the A's to ground.

If you want a falling-edge trigger, you trigger one or both of the A inputs, and hard-wire B to "high".  NOTE: If you trigger only one A input, you MUST hard-wire the other (unused) A input to "high."

I think that most users should just stop here.  The '121 is a building block, and you use it just as I just described, just follow the "recipe" and don't think.  It will work :)

Now, of course it IS possible to do more sophisticated things, by doing all sorts of weird timings and transitions to the (count 'em - three!) inputs in different ways.  However, making that work would require a 100% understanding of the truth table.  But I would be asking "do I really want to be doing this...?".

To precisely answer your question, you NEVER transition BOTH an A and a B together.  You're either rising on B (A's staying put) or falling on A (B staying put).  In both cases, all other inputs have to follow the truth table (i.e., "staying put" at the CORRECT level, not "any" level) for it to trigger.